# Call getData inside widget block class

Tags: magento2, blocks

Is it possible to call getdata() from inside the block class like this? Because as it is now, i get no data from getdata().

```
    class Index extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
protected $_template = "";

public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);   
    
    if($this->getData('template_layout') == "LPS" )
    {
        $this->_template = "widget/Image_left.phtml";   
            
    }else if($this->getData('template_layout') == "RPS")
    {
        $this->_template = "widget/Image_right.phtml";
    }
    else if($this->getData('template_layout') == "RPWS")
    {
        $this->_template = "widget/Image_right_No_Space.phtml";
    }
    else if($this->getData('template_layout') == "LPWS")
    {
        $this->_template = "widget/Image_right_No_Space.phtml";
    }else{
        $this->_template = "widget/Image_right.phtml";
        
    }

  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->getData('test')` is only a shortcut for `$this->test` So if your getData returns null it's because your `this` object do not have the property you are looking for I guess.

May be you can provide more context. Also with this kind of condition consider using a switch case :)

Comment: I just want to get the value of template_layout, so i can switch between templates. I get the value from my widget.xml. Everything works, but the only thing i cant seem to do is to access the "template_layout" to get the value

Comment: Have you considered using `$this->getLayout()` ?